# Why do visa applications require birth certificate?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, working-visas

It seems for quite some countries (e.g. Japan, Austria), getting a long-term visa (e.g. work visa) requires submitting one's birth certificate.

What information do immigration departments require from a birth certificate that isn't available from a passport?

Comment: Birth certificate may be harder to forge. And birth certificate often includes your parents.

Comment: One reason is that visa applicants who are under the age of 18 must typically provide written consent that demonstrates their application is supported by their parent(s) or legal guardian. A birth (or adoption) certificate is evidence of their relationship with their parents or legal guardian who have provided consent in support of their application.

Comment: Because those countries have a very high incidence of visa fraud and they want to make sure you're really you. A birth certificate can be checked with your country's authorities and help ascertain that you're really who your passport says you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It has your parent(s) full names, at least the mother in some cases, which is one of the ways to identify people who have the same name.
2. It has your birth name.
3. It has your birth city and country, while most passports do not have them currently.
4. Finally, if you are into fraud, that's one more document you have to take care of, making it harder for you.